# Z3 python treats x**2 different than x*x?

Tags: z3, z3py

It seems that Z3 Python interface doesn't like the  ** operator , it can deal with x*x but not x**2 as shown in the example below

```
>>> x,y = x,y=Reals('x y')
>>> z3.prove(Implies(x -6 == 0,x**2 -36 == 0))
failed to prove
[x = 6]
>>> z3.prove(Implies(x -6 == 0,x*x -36 == 0))
proved
```

Comment: I am not sure how z3 treats these 2 internally -- but the problem is fixed by moving to 4.3.1 as suggested by Leonardo below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using version 4.3.0 on Linux or OSX. Version 4.3.0 has a configuration problem on these platforms. If that is the case, I suggest you download version [4.3.1](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89c1785b7322). Version 4.3.1 will prove both queries on Linux and OSX. In version 4.3.0 auto-configuration is not enabled by default on Linux and OSX. Thus, Z3 will always use a general purpose solver that is not complete for nonlinear arithmetic, nor has support for the power operator. When auto-configuration is enabled, Z3 detects that these two problems are in the nonlinear real arithmetic fragment, and switches to the [nlsat solver](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/IJCAR2012.pdf).

BTW, to manually enable auto-configuration on version 4.3.0, you may use the command `z3.set_option(auto_config=True)`.